# How to start tab suggestions in csh?

Tags: linux, shell, kde, csh

In a different distro of linux I had bash tab suggestions enabled. Now I am using Konsole with csh on my pc. how do we enable tab completion in csh?

By tab suggestions I mean that if I type /home/abc_ followed by tab twice, it should show the suggestions abc_1 abc_2.

If there is only one option then then tab completion works but in case of multiple options I want to see all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ~/.cshrc put

```
set filec
set autolist
```

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>ctrl-D</kbd> once you started typing and you'll get all the suggestions.  However, hitting <kbd>ctrl-D</kbd> without first typing at least one letter will close the terminal.